# MySql Replication Scenario

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a problem defining the best way to replicate and synchronize some information that I have in different mysql servers.

Let me explain:

**Actual Scenario:**

**Server A**
-Table A1 *(read/write) Operations*
-Table A2 *(read/write) Operations*

**Server B**
-Table B1 *(write) Operations*

**Desired Scenario:**

**Server A**
-Table A1 *(read/write) Operations*
-Table A2 *(read/write) Operations*
**-Table replicated B1 *(read) Operations***

**Server B**
-Table B1 *(write) Operations*
**-Table A1 replicated *(read) Operations***
**-Table A2 replicated *(read) Operations***

How should I define my mysql replication configuration?

Should I define the two servers as Master?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this kind of replication with MySQL. Please have a look at the following [slave options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db)

- `replicate-do-db`
- `replicate-ignore-db`
- `replicate-do-table`
- `replicate-ignore-table`
- `replicate-ignore-table`
- `replicate-wild-do-table`
- `replicate-wild-ignore-table`

and the [corresponding annotations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-rules.html). With these options you can setup both servers to be mutual slaves and restrict the tables (databases) to be replicated. As MySQL is not able to do a multi-master replication you have to ensure that all *writes* are directed to the correct server and that nothing gets written into replicated tables.

Comment: Anybody looking at replication filtering check out "replicate-wild-ignore-table". I'm still checking it out myself but it looks like it is best practice and don't use replicate-do-db replicate-ignore-db ever.